# Right Click not Working with Files in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: usb, mount, 18.04, 17.10, files

Recently, I Upgraded my Ubuntu OS from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS .
Yesterday, a friend of mine gave me a USB to format. Previously, whenever I needed to format USB, after mounting USB device on right-click the options used to appear.

But now in Ubuntu 18.04, when I mounted my friend's USB, I was unable to format it, as right clicking on mounted USB device was non-functional option.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, I found files app was revamped, does this have anything to do with update ?

Anyone faced the same situation , please let me know what you did to fix this issue .

---

Edit : Just now discovered, what was wrong, Ubuntu no longer supports physical right-click.
To perform right-click operation, just try 2 fingered tap, so easy !

Comment: I had that same experience,change they say is constant